# Starting Threads in Sequence

Tags: c++, multithreading

My goal is to have a set of threads run and then once they are completed, another set of threads begins. When I try to run the following code I get nothing happening after the first group of threads execution.

The code I am trying to implement is like the following:

```
int main() {

    std::vector<thread> ths;
    Gallery = new Lanes(16);
    int totalRate = redRate + blueRate;

    // Coarse grain - 1 lane at a time
    ths.push_back(std::thread(&ShooterActionCoarse,redRate,red, numRound));
    ths.push_back(std::thread(&ShooterActionCoarse,blueRate,blue, numRound));
    ths.push_back(std::thread(&CleanerCoarse));
    ths.push_back(std::thread(&Printer,totalRate));

    for (auto& th : ths) {
        th.join();
    }
    ths.clear();
    // Coarse grain - 2 lanes at a time
    ths.push_back(std::thread(&ShooterActionCoarse2,redRate,red, numRound));
    ths.push_back(std::thread(&ShooterActionCoarse2,blueRate,blue, numRound));
    ths.push_back(std::thread(&CleanerCoarse));
    ths.push_back(std::thread(&Printer,totalRate));

    for (auto& th : ths) {
        th.join();

}
```

Comment: "a set of threads" sounds like a "job" or "task"

Comment: Threads are expensive to create. This is not how you would tipically use them. Normally you would have a pool of threads. You pass a set of jobs to the pool. Once those jobs are complete you pass a new set of jobs to the pool.

Comment: @GregorMcGregor Yup, just fixed that but when I do this, nothing happens after the end of the first group of threads

Comment: @LokiAstari do you have an idea how I could implement that to my code?

Comment: Yes look up thread pool.

Comment: Well even if I used a thread pool, that wouldnt exactly make my program work

Comment: What does "nothing happens" mean? Does the program hang, or does it progress silently? And what do you expect to happen? Show enough code for us to reproduce the issue: a [mcve].

Comment: Yes it just hangs. Unfortunetly I can't show the thread functions because of how lengthy they are